# React props not showing up in the Child component (but I can see they exist in debug mode)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I have been creating a simple React project (not using Redux) and I'm having issues passing the state from the parent into the Child component. I've watched multiple tutorials and went through with the Chrome debugger and still cannot figure out the issue.

I am passing a list of song-tracks from the Parent (App) to the Child (PlaylistOptions), however, when I log the list of songs it is empty until like the 3rd load (screenshot attached). Another weird thing that happens is I'm able to access the first song right away but makes the whole app crash. I have tried changing my child from a function to a class, and also have added a componentWillMount in the child with a wait time for the props to load but nothing solved my problem.

Here is how I'm passing the state into the child component:

```
<PlaylistOptions 
  wait={5000}
  items={this.state.items} 
  next={this.state.next}
  previous={this.state.previous}
  offset={this.state.offset}
  limit={this.state.limit}
  token={this.state.token}
/>
```

This is what the console shows of my items array (the array is empty until the 3rd load I have no idea why)

[result of logging items array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlXpe.png)

Errors from trying to access the second element of the array

[error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYcTu.png)

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Oovu.png)

Comment: please post the code directly here, it is not handy to look at an image in another tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access the 2nd element of the items array being passed in as a prop. Take a look at how many items are in the items array in your initial state. You're trying to access an item that doesn't exist, and that's throwing an error.

Instead of accessing the indices of the array directly, you can map over the array to generate a list dynamically based on the number of entries in the array.

```
<div>
    Song List
    {this.props.items.map((item, i) => {
       return(`Song ${i} - ${item.track.name}`);
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: It can have multiple tracks, but the initial state only has one track in it. Your initial state is being passed down into the child component, where it tries to access the second item, which doesn't yet exist!

Comment: I just updated my post to include the code where I set the state for the items array (the response for the spotify api call is an array of items (and each item contains track object) did I set the state incorrectly then? I don't understand how it could only save item in the array the response has 20 items

Comment: Ok, so API calls are asynchronous, meaning that the rest of your code isn't going to wait for them to finish executing before rendering. It will render your child component using the default state, and then once the api call returns and the state is updated, it will re-render the child component again using the updated state

Comment: That makes sense thank you, but when I ran that code snippet here is what printed onto my page:    Song ListSong 0 - undefinedSong 1 - undefinedSong 2 - undefinedSong 3 - undefinedSong 4 - undefinedSong 5 - undefinedSong 6 - undefinedSong 7 - undefinedSong 8 - undefinedSong 9 - undefinedSong 10 - undefinedSong 11 - undefinedSong 12 - undefinedSong 13 - undefinedSong 14 - undefinedSong 15 - undefinedSong 16 - undefinedSong 17 - undefinedSong 18 - undefinedSong 19 - undefined

Comment: Hmm, and what does console.log(this.props.items) print out?. I had a typo in my code before, and I did track.name instead of item.track.name, are you using the most recent snippet?

Comment: It worked with your most recent code snippet, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete example of how you pass data from parent component to child component in **React**:

**Parent Component**

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import PChild from "./PChild";

class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let json = [];
        json.push({track: { id:1, name: 'Black Sabbath, from the album Black Sabbath (1970)'}});
        json.push({track: { id:2, name: 'Blackfield, from the album Blackfield (2004)'}});
        json.push({track: { id:3, name: 'Bo Diddley, from the album Bo Diddley (1958)'}});
        json.push({track: { id:4, name: 'Damn Yankees, from the album Damn Yankees (1990)'}});
        this.setState({items: json});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PChild items={this.state.items}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

// Parent to Child communication
class PChild extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.items.map((item, i) => {
                    return <li key={item.track.id}>
                        {(`Item ${i+1} - ${item.track.name}`)}
                    </li>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PChild;
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the problem was I was trying to access the elements directly in the child before my API call in the parent was finished